# Сериализация DTO объекта. Json

Tags: java, json, spring, dto

Есть класс Building.

```
Building{
Long Id; 
String name; 
Integer countRooms; 
}
```

И есть класс Room

```
Room{
Long Id; 
String name; 
Building building; 
}
```

Когда я делаю запрос 
/buildings?id=1
Выводится JSON как мне и нужно.

```
{
"id": 1, 
"name":name,  
"counRooms": 1
}
```

А когда делаю запрос 
/rooms?id=1
Выводится JSON

```
{
"id":1, 
"name": name, 
"buiding":{
"id": 1, 
"name":name,  
"countRooms": 1
}
```

Но мне в этом ответе поле countRooms не нужно.  Пробовал JsonIgnore но тогда это поле не выводится в первом случае . 
 Помогите разобраться. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Dto для того и предназначен чтобы хранить в себе данные только те которые нужны. Если вам сильно мешает лишнее поле пишите ещё один класс без этого поля и возвращайте только его или же пишите свой сериализатор

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить при помощи аннотации Jackson `@JsonView`. Эта аннотация позволяет включать или исключать поля объекта, попадающие в сериализованный объект, в зависимости от условия - активного view. Возьмём, например, вот такой код:

```
// Класс, содержащий интерфейсы, которыми мы будем обозначать наши view
public class Views {
    public interface Public {}
    public interface Private extends Public {};
}

// При активном Views.Public включаются все поля...
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
public class Bean {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    // ... кроме поля secret. Поле secret включится при активном Views.Private.
    // Так как Views.Private - наследник Views.Public, то при активном Views.Private
    // будет также активен и Views.Public, а значит, будут включены и поля, включённые
    // при активном Views.Public
    @JsonView(Views.Private.class)
    private String secret;
    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Теперь укажем контроллеру, какой view использовать для сериализации:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    // В ответе будут поля id и name
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public Bean getPublic() {
        return new Bean(1, "name", "secret");
    }

    // В ответе будут поля id, name и secret
    @JsonView(Views.Private.class)
    public Bean getPrivate() {
        return new Bean(1, "name", "secret");
    }
}
```

Применительно к вашей задаче, вам нужно будет создать два view - `RoomView` и `BuildingView` (наследник `RoomView`). `RoomView` нужно навесить на классы `Room` и `Building`, а `BuildingView` - на поле `Building.countRooms`. Также нужно навесить `RoomView` на контроллер `/rooms` и `BuildingView` на контроллер `/buildings`. После этого `/buildings` будет возвращать JSON с полем `countRooms`, а `/rooms` - без него.

Подробнее про JSON Views в Jackson можно почитать [здесь](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) или [здесь](https://habr.com/post/307392/).